# How to set name for dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

I'm doing a user management page for a personal project and I want to rename every combobox
distinguishing if it is a combo linked to a menu, a tab or a function to make database management easier. Indeed, depending on the permissions, users can do what admins decide what they can do.

This is the code that I've written so far:

```
<div class="card card-block bg-white">
<label for="permessimenu" class="col-sm-12">Menu</label>
@foreach (var colMenu in ManageMenu.GetAll())
{
    <div class="col-sm-12">
        <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-4" name="combo_m"><label>@colMenu.Description</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <select class="form-control" style="overflow:auto;" id="Description">
                <option id="tipoUtente" value="0">&lt;Permesso&gt;</option>
                @foreach (var menu in
                              Permission.GetAll())
                {
                    <option value="@menu.Id">@menu.Description</option>
                }
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
    </div>
    @foreach (var colTab in GestioneTab.Select(new WhereStatementBuilder() { { GestioneTab.Empty.IdMenu, Operator.Equals, colMenu.Id.Get() } }))
    {
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <label>@colTab.Description</label>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-1"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-3">
                <select class="form-control" style="overflow:auto;" id="Description">
                    <option id="tipoUtente" value="0">&lt;Permesso&gt;</option>
                    @foreach (var tab in
                                    Permission.GetAll())
                    {
                        <option value="@tab.Id">@tab.Description</option>
                    }
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
        </div>
        @foreach (var colFunzioni in FuncPermission.Select(new WhereStatementBuilder() { { FuncPermission.Empty.IdTab, Operator.Equals, colTab.Id.Get() } }))
        {
            <div class="col-sm-12">
                <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <label >@colFun.Description</label>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3">
                    <select class="form-control" style="overflow:auto;" id="Description">
                        <option id="userType" value="0">&lt;Permesso&gt;</option>
                        @foreach (var user in
                                         Permission.GetAll())
                        {
                            <option value="@user.Id">@user.Description</option>
                        }                        
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
            </div>
        }
    }
}
```

What I'd like to do is to have combobox named like this: combo_menu_1, combo_menu_2, combo_tab_1, combo_tab_2, combo_func_1, combo_func_2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array in HTML like this
combo_menu[]
combo_tab[]